# ComboBox from filtered list

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried for a while to find (search) a solution to this but can't seem to.

I'm trying to read a list from an excel document, and based on the "country" item (which is selected on another combobox) filter the list. If it is the right country I want to add the row (4 items) to the combobox row.

I can't use a array because the length changes by country, and since only the second dimension of the array can be dynamic it populates the list backwards.

I currently get this error:

> Assignment to constant not permitted.

The code:

```
Private Sub P_Country_Change()

    Dim LastR As Integer

    LastR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("A2", Worksheets("M_DB").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0

        For i = 2 To LastR
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("E" & i).Value = P_Country.Value Then

            With Press_m
                .AddItem = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("A" & i).Value
                .List(j, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("B" & i).Value 
                .List(j, 2) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("C" & i).Value 
                .List(j, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("D" & i).Value 
            End With

                j = j + 1

            End If
        Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I made it work. I'm not sure exactly what I did right, but to help anyone else using this as a referenace, one thing I did that may have been it was set the properties of the combobox to:

```
locked = False
```

Also I changed the code a little bit, but not so much, here it is now:

Private Sub P_Country_Change()

```
Dim LastR As Integer

LastR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("A2", Worksheets("M_DB").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Dim j As Integer
j = 0

For s = P_m.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    P_m.RemoveItem s
Next s

With P_m
    .ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnWidths = "125;125;125;125"
    .ColumnHeads = False
End With

    For i = 2 To LastR
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("E" & i).Value = Press_Country.Value Then

            P_m.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("B" & i).Value ' Name
            P_m.List(j, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("C" & i).Value ' Corporation
            P_m.List(j, 2) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("D" & i).Value ' Province
            P_m.List(j, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("M_DB").Range("E" & i).Value ' City

            j = j + 1

        End If
    Next i
```

End Sub

Finally, [I found a great referance here.](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=128:excel-userform-controls-combobox-and-listbox-additem-method-boundcolumn-list-property-listindex-rowsource-selected-property#Add%20Items/Data%20to%20(Populate)%20a%20ListBox%20or%20ComboBox) teach me right? RTFM first ;-)